# App Engine Multi-version routing and support

Tags: google-app-engine

While App Engine supports multi-versioning of an API via URL end points, we can't let/ask our end users change the URL every time there's an API update. Is there a way via routes or URL to dispatch the request to one of the versions?

For instance: `<host>/v11/pasta/ravioli`

Should call the pasta handler for version 11 and a request `<host>/v10/pasta/ravioli/` should route to the pasta handler of version 10.

TIA.

Comment: How is `<host>/v10/pasta/ravioli/` and `<host>/v11/pasta/ravioli/` not changing the URL?

Comment: The idea being the users of the old api can keep using the old url while we can release a new api for another set of users concurrently.

Comment: Have you considered using separate AppEngine application versions? E.g. `http://v10.your_app_id.appspot.com` serving v10, `http://v11.your_app_id.appspot.com` serving v11, and `http://your_app_id.appspot.com` defaulting to the latest version. See https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime#Requests_and_Domains

Comment: Some people weren't happy with that approach due to the mess with SSL certs. But, I haven't yet found a more reasonable approach.

Comment: To avoid that mess, AppEngine also allows you to use `-dot-` instead of `.` to address a version, i.e. `v10-dot-your_app_id.appspot.com` is equivalent to `v10.your_app_id.appspot.com` (also works for nested "subdomains", only `your_app_id.appspot.com` has to use actual dots, obviously).

Comment: Ahhh that's interesting, never saw that in their docs. I will give it a go and report back. If it works would be fantastic.

Comment: Bah, good idea, but it's not going to work. We have the app under a custom domain name and I just realized we have the subdomains on our corporate DNS server, dang. Any other ideas? :D

Comment: I think I'm going to have to brute-force it and add a whole copy of the of each version of the app as a py module and go crazy with the routing. I think it's the only way I can meet those requirements, although I'm aware not the most efficient or optimal.

Comment: @rdodev - I'm facing the same problem, did you found a better solution?